# Convert chart image to php using data on chart

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have charts that have x and y data.  Is there a way to somehow read the image via a script and grab the relevant data?

Example: X row at bottom of chart displays time in days.  Y row on side displays a number, say 15 for example.

Is there a way to read that data using some library/helper?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean read chart data from image using php?

Comment: Can the GD library perform OCR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an OCR library/software to get the statistical data.

There is this:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html

But that might not work well.

You should probably find an CLI app that works well for you, and call it from PHP. I assume you are using linux. The exec command will work under Windows. See this comment for more details:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101579

Comment: I will look into the OCR library and see how well it works. I will be back with the results.

Comment: Well it turns out the client went a different route, which means I don't have to grab text from any images. 
I started using the class you suggested from phpclasses.org.  I was making progress when they changed direction!  I will play around some more with that class and see what it can do.

Comment: I see. I can't remember a time a client didn't do that to me. Good luck with the new spec!